# How to use different fonts for different languages in ngx-translate?

Tags: angular, typescript, fonts, ngx-translate

I'm using angular 4 and ngx-translate. i have a multi language app and i want to use a special font for one of the languages.

here is part of my html:

```
<ngx-datatable-column prop="title">
<ng-template let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn" ngx-datatable-header-template>
  <span (click)="sort()" class="font">{{'IncomingTable.Title' | translate}}</span>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
 <a (click)="showViewForm(row);showView=true;showIncomingTable=false">{{value}} </a>
</ng-template>
```

and this is scss:

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'IRANSansWeb_Medium';
  src: url($IRANSansWeb_Medium_woff_path) format('woff'),
  url($IRANSansWeb_Medium_woff2_path) format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.font{
  font-family:'IRANSansWeb_Medium';
}
```

i have two languages and i want to use this font-family only for one language! what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to set some class on the app component element, something like:

```
<app class="IRANLang"></app>
```

And then define css like this:

```
app {
  font-family: 'SansWeb_Medium';
}
app.IRANLang {
  font-family: 'IRANSansWeb_Medium';
}
```

Naturally you want to subscribe to Router's `NavigationEnd` event to check for the language changes, or wrap the TranslateService's `useLang` method where you'd set your app's style.

**UPDATE**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  private _selectedLang: string;    

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) { 
    // ... you language initialization here
    // please set this._selectedLang to your default language
  }

  @HostBinding('class.IRANLang')
  get iranLangClass() {
    return this._selectedLang === 'fa'; // or some other language code
  }

  changeLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
    this._selectedLang = lang;
  }
}
```

Comment: and how should i assign IRANLang to my language?

Comment: You can use HostBinding on AppComponent. I will extend the answer